# Unpredictable JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am receiving a JSON structure that is somewhat unpredictable from a third party API.
For example, I started with a class like this:

```
public Class UserTuple
{
    public int uid {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,int> stats {get; set;}
    //Unknown structure here (Although I know its name)...
}
```

I can potentially make a class for this, but it will be quite nested...I do not care about the values in this part, so it seems like a waste. 
Is there a way to let JSON.NET know to ignore this unknown section?

PS: I am deserializing in this way:

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<UserTuple>>(receivedJSON);
```

Comment: it will be easy if you post your JSON structure returned

Comment: At first I had simply a List<string> in there, but it soon started to error out, saying along the lines of "Unexpected token at line so and so..." and I narrowed it down to this part of JSON.

Comment: If you are not interested in that properties, **don't declare it**. Json.Net will ignore them.

Comment: Jon's solution works perfectly, L.B. suggestion works fine also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care about it, it seems like you just need to set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MissingMemberHandling.htm) appropriately:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
};
var tuples = JsonConvert.DeserialiazeObject<List<UserTuple>>(json, settings);
```

Comment: Upon further testing, it appears that this solution works best in scenarios  where the model requests for values that may not always be provided by JSON. Otherwise if I don't know the structure of a property in JSON, it is best to simply omit it from the model as L.B. suggested.